# Looking to scrape and store values from a table in HTML getting values in <tr> tag

Tags: python, html, pandas, data-structures, beautifulsoup

Im looking to scrape a table and store the values by data-* in a dictionary. One because there are two tables in the HTML file, how can only scrape the second table? The second issue I'm having is getting the values from the  tag.

**For example:**
`

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-abc="1.2.3">
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>1.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-def="4.5.6">
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>2.0,3.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ghi="7.8.9">
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>4.0</td>
    </tr>
```

`

I've seen where you can use the following syntax:

`rows = soup.findAll('tr', {'class': cond})`

*But how can I access the `data-abc` values?*

**Below is the current implementation:**

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas.io.html import read_html
    
    dfs = pd.read_html('test.html', header=0)
    for df in dfs:
        print(df)
```

Output:

```
    [15 rows x 7 columns]
         Name  Version
    0      test1      1.0
    1      test2      2.0, 3.0
    2      test3      4.0
```

**Expected output(data-abc does not need to show be displayed):**

```
    data-abc= 1.2.3
         Name  Version
    0      test1      1.0
    0      test1      2.0, 3.0
    
    data-def= 4.5.6
         Name  Version
    0      test1      2.0, 3.0
    0      test2      2.0
    
    data-ghi= 7.8.9
         Name  Version
    0      test1      4.0
    1      test2      2.0, 3.0
```

Comment: `data-abc` is normal parameter like `href` in `<a>` or `scr` in `<img>` so you get it in the same way in BeautifulSoup - `item["data-abc"]`

Comment: BTW: get both tables and use `all_tables[1]` to use only second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data-abc` is normal parameter like `href` in `<a>` or `scr` in `<img>` so you get it in the same way in `BeautifulSoup` - `item["data-abc"]` or `item.attrs['data-abc']` or ` item.attrs.get('data-abc').

Because `item.attrs` is a dictionary so you can get all `.keys()` and use loop to check which one starts with `data-`

**EDIT:** I add `item.find_all('td')` to get values in rows

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''    <tr data-abc="1.2.3">
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>1.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-def="4.5.6">
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>2.0,3.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ghi="7.8.9">
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>4.0</td>
    </tr>'''

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

all_items = soup.find_all('tr')

for item in all_items:
    for key in item.attrs.keys():
        if key.startswith('data-'):
            print(key, item[key])
            #print(key, item.attrs[key])   
            #print(key, item.attrs.get(key))

            rows = item.find_all('td')
            print('     Name:', rows[0].text)
            print('  Version:', rows[1].text)
```

Result:

```
data-abc 1.2.3
     Name: test1
  Version: 1.0
data-def 4.5.6
     Name: test2
  Version: 2.0,3.0
data-ghi 7.8.9
     Name: test3
  Version: 4.0
```

---

You can keep it in dictionary with nested list or dictionary

```
data = {}

for item in all_items:
    for key in item.attrs.keys():
        if key.startswith('data-'):
            print(key, item[key])
            #print(key, item.attrs[key])   
            #print(key, item.attrs.get(key))
            rows = item.find_all('td')
            print('     Name:', rows[0].text)
            print('  Version:', rows[1].text)
            if item[key] not in data:
                data[ item[key] ] = []
            data[ item[key] ].append({
                'Name': rows[0].text,
                'Version': rows[1].text,
            })

import pprint            
pprint.pprint(data)
```

Result:

```
{'1.2.3': [{'Name': 'test1', 'Version': '1.0'}],
 '4.5.6': [{'Name': 'test2', 'Version': '2.0,3.0'}],
 '7.8.9': [{'Name': 'test3', 'Version': '4.0'}]}
```

And now you have all data and you can format output as you like.

---

**EDIT:** I assumed you may have more elements with `'1.2.3'` so I created list with directory - so you need `[0]` to get first element from list -

```
print( data['1.2.3'][0]['Name'] )
```

You can also use `for`-loop - especially if you will have more elements

```
for item in data['1.2.3']:
    print( item['Name'] )
```

If you expect only one element with `'1.2.3'` then you can assign dictionary directly

```
data[ item[key] ] = {'Name': rows[0].text, 'Version': rows[1].text}
```

and then you don't need `[0]`

```
print( data['1.2.3']['Name'] )
```

Comment: Looks like `data- `is the key and the *.*.* are the `values`, what I'm looking for is to make only the `version(1.2.3)` the `key` and the `name(test*)` and `version(1.0)` the `values`. 
What I just realized is that a dictionary is probably not the best way to structure this since it only takes one value per key. The objective is to look up by `data-*` and compare `name:test*` `version:1.2.3` to an existing `name` and `version`. Is there a better way to structure?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to create but inside dictionary you can use list or other dictionary to keep many values.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, didnt think about using the dictionary that way!

Comment: In the second method how can I access a specific `'Name'`, I've tried `print(['1.2.3']['Name'][test1])` and I get an **Error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**.

Is there a way to call a specific `'Name'` and get that `'Version'`?

Comment: I assumed you may have more elements with `'1.2.3'` so I created list with directory - so you need `[0]` to get first element from list - `['1.2.3'][0]['Name']`. OR you would have to create data in different way - directly assign `data[ item[key] ] = {'Name': rows[0].text, 'Version': rows[1].text}`